# Installing Android application programmatically after download from the server

Tags: android, android-intent

I have developed an Android application, kept the .apk file in the server. I developed one html file and given the link of that .apk file in html. If I click on the link, The file is downloading. Now my task is to install the application programmatically with out the use of user. I had given code like this:

```
File fullPath = getFileStreamPath("Timing example.apk");
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "Timing example.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    startActivity(intent);  
}
```

Comment: Do you want to notify the user to replace the existing application as we do update any software??

Comment: yes, I want to make notify.

Comment: you should be aware that this is discouraged by the nice people who made android. apps should only be installed via the play store.. and never without user intervention.

Comment: If it is for the first time i.e there is no existing application in device, Then it has to install automatically without the need of user.

Comment: Oren.. In Google, I find methods to install android app automatically hence I am trying the same as I am new to android applications. oren

Comment: The code you mentioned aboe, is the right one. what else you want to know mate

Comment: Actually code is correct but my .apk file is not able to install automatically after download. I had given user-permissions as well in menifest file. Is there any changes or any new code to give regarding this..

Comment: Thats how android works, unless user grants permission, apps cannot install! Other hacks and ways are strongly discouraged. Follow standard android ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now my task is to install the application programatically with out the use of user

Fortunately, this is not possible for an ordinary Android SDK application, for obvious security reasons.